# Overiding URL pattern from a third party app

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I am using django-registration app and I am implementing the Remember me functionality [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1881/)

Basically, the registration app, needs you to define one URL only,

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

under the hood, it defines default urls like `/accounts/login`, `/accounts/logout`, each of which points to `django.contrib.auth.views` functions.

I need to overwrite the `login()` function, as well as the accompanying URL.

So how do I overwrite URL `accounts/login` in my `urls.py`, keeping all the rest urls as default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will use the first URL pattern that matches. So in your `urls.py`, add a pattern for `accounts/login` *before* you include the urls from django-registration. All other URLs will be handled by django-registration.

Answer (score 1):

You could try explicitly catching the `accounts/login` url request before it hits your more general `accounts/*` url catcher.

Maybe

```
# first catch your custom login
url(r'^accounts/login', include('my_custom_login.urls')), 
# and everything else beginning with accounts/
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```